# CSS for <img> next to <div> with text and min-width

Tags: html, css

Following HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
</body>
```

The text block should be right next to the image and should float below the image only when `min-width` is underrun.

I tried the following CSS:

```
img {
    float: left;
}
div {
    float: left;
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

... don't work because long text always floats below the image (inherent property of a `<div>`, it wants to be as wide as possible). I don't want to specify a fixed `width` for the text block!

Layout example in different size (how I imagine):
[image]
(a), (b), (c)

(c) text block underrun it's `min-width` -> place below the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use the calc() property to set a max-width for the text div, depending on the width of the image.
(Run the snippet and choose Full Page to see the effect while resizing your browser window.)

```css
img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 400px;
}
div {
    float: left;
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 400px);
    max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 400px);
    max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 400px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
</body>
```

As pointed out by @C-Link_Nepal, this is a CSS3 feature not yet natively supported by all browsers. Use http://caniuse.com/#search=calc to check your target browsers.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Is `calc` CSS3?

Comment: @jakob That's css3 feature. Before using make sure to check can I use calc css?

Comment: Correct, that's why I used the most common prefixes for the max-width rule. Use http://caniuse.com/#search=calc to check for support by your target browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply overflow property of css to the div:

```
img {
    float: left;
}
div {
    float: left;
    min-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden; /* this makes sure the text not go below the image */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you get me wrong, I hope the image illustrate what I want.

Comment: I just tried in Chrome. The text block is always below the image except the browser window is extremly wide. I want it to be next to the image until `min-width` is underrun.